# What is wrong with this javascript if statement

Tags: javascript

Javascript Function to show/hide tabs and iFrames:

```
function ChangeStep(id)
{
    var i = 1;
    // hide all other tabs:
    while(i<3) {
        var divID = 'tabs' + i;
        if (divID !== null) {
            document.getElementById(divID).className = " hide";
        }
        i++;
    }

    // show this one
    document.getElementById(id).className = " show";
}

if (id == "tab2") {
    document.getElementById(iFrame).className = " iFrame2";
}
else if (id == "tab1") {
    document.getElementById(iFrame).className = " iFrame1";
}
```

The change of tab works, but the if statement at the bottom doesn't seem to work.

### **EDIT**

The issue is that I have an iFrame with the id of `'iFrame'`.
 Now I made 2 Classes in the css file called: `'iFrame1'` and `'iFrame2'` which have different settings and which make the iFrame look different. 
The function above has no problem in changing the `'tabs'` (*Add the class 'Show' to one and 'Hide' to all others*). 
But it doesn't seem to change the iFrames class to `'iFrame2' and/or 'iFrame1'` 
I can't put it on JSFiddle because my site heavily relies on images, so I'll just link you to where I have it uploaded: [www.FeedtheSyrians.com](http://www.FeedtheSyrians.com)

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for this, would help us understand more of what the issue is

Comment: `var divID = 'tabs' + i; if (divID !== null)`... How would you expect it to be null when you've just assigned a string to it? You're supposed to perform `document.getElementById` first, or just remove that `if` statement altogether.

Comment: If you indent properly you will find it easier to debug. http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Sorry, I'll try putting it in Jsfiddle now

Comment: Please don't edit your question so that the answers no longer make sense. (Hence the rollback)

Comment: @Fabrício Matté If I wanted to add more tabs, then I could change it to `code`)

Comment: You can edit your question so that it includes #Update and the next version, so old answers make sense whilst you improve the question.

Comment: Edit (Make it more clear): Ok, so: The issue is that I have an iFrame with the id of 'iFrame'. Now I made 2 Classes in the css file called: 'iFrame1' and 'iFrame2' which have different settings and which make the iFrame look different. The function above has no problem in changing the 'tabs' (Add the class 'Show' to one and 'Hide' to all others. But it doesn't seem to change the iFrames class to 'iFrame2' and/or 'iFrame1'

I can't put it on JSFiddle because my site heavily relies on images, so I'll just link you to where I have it uploaded: www.FeedtheSyrians.com

Comment: @ShivamAmin looking at the page you've linked to, you should be using `document.getElementById('iFrame').className = iframeClass;` as you do not have a variable called `iFrame` which is set to 'iFrame'.

Comment: Site seems to have it working now.

Answer (score 5):

Your if statement isn't inside of the function body meaning it is not executed when the function is called.

I don't know when it will be executed. I'm no JS expert and I don't want to make an (educated) guess, maybe someone with more knowledge can say.

Comment: Ok, I put the if statement in the function (Was changing it around a few minutes ago, and didn't notice I put it outside), but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be defining the variable `iFrame` anywhere?

```
function ChangeStep(id)
{
  var iframeClass, iFrame = '???', divID, i;
  // hide all other tabs:
  for ( i=1; i<3; i++ ) 
  {
    divID = 'tabs' + i;
    if (divID != id) 
    {
      document.getElementById(divID).className = 'hide';
    }
  }
  // show this one
  document.getElementById(id).className = 'show';
  // show the iframe
  switch (id) 
  {
    case 'tab2': iframeClass = 'iFrame2'; break;
    case 'tab1': iframeClass = 'iFrame1'; break;
  }
  if ( iframeClass ) {
    document.getElementById(iFrame).className = iframeClass;
  }
}
```

Also would you not want different iframes to be hidden and shown when a different tab is used? Rather than just applying a class to a singular iframe? Anyway, just my two cents.

#### update

From what I've seen of the site you've linked to you should be using this line of code:

```
document.getElementById('iFrame').className = iframeClass;
```

Either that or you should define a variable before that, as I've done in my example above, and set `iFrame = 'iFrame'` rather than `'???'`.

On an entirely separate note I would avoid using that favicon for your site ;)

#### update 2

The problem is down to this part:

```
switch (id) 
{
  case 'tab2': iframeClass = 'iFrame2'; break;
  case 'tab1': iframeClass = 'iFrame1'; break;
}
```

It seems from looking at your site that you actually need:

```
switch (id) 
{
  case 'tabs2': iframeClass = 'iFrame2'; break;
  case 'tabs1': iframeClass = 'iFrame1'; break;
}
```

*note the added 's' to make 'tabs1' and 'tabs2'*

Comment: If I use 2 iFrames, then the Form will be different. I'm trying to get them to fill out the 'Sign Petition' form on Change.org by showing them a part of it at a time.

Comment: @ShivamAmin Sure thing, now that I've seen the site it makes more sense what you are trying to do. My update should fix the issue you are having.

Comment: Ok, I changed the Function to what you said, but the iFrame still looks the same. I know my Css is fine because when I manually change the class name, it changes it.

I changed the '???' and changed it to 'iFrame' after copying your code, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: @ShivamAmin it seems the problem is down to an typo in your original code. You should be checking for `'tabs1'` and `'tabs2'`, not `'tab1'` and `'tab2'` (see my update above). The best way to debug problems like this is, if in doubt, `console.log` all the values you are dealing with... the `console` is your friend :)

Answer (score 0):

You had 2 problems , the closing bracket for the function was before the if statement  , also I dont see anywhere that `id` is defined. you are getting element by `id`, but unless it is dfined somwhere else that is probaby the problem

```
function ChangeStep(id)
{
var i = 1;
// hide all other tabs:
while(i<3) {
    var divID = 'tabs' + i;
    if (divID !== null) {
   document.getElementById(divID).className = " hide";
    }
    i++;
    }

// show this one
document.getElementById(id).className = " show";
//} -- remove this
    if (id == "tab2") {
        document.getElementById(iFrame).className = " iFrame2";
    }
    else if (id == "tab1") {
        document.getElementById(iFrame).className = " iFrame1";
    }
} //add this
```

Comment: This is how it gets the id
'onClick="ChangeState(tabs1)" and onClick="ChangeState(tabs2)"'

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong with these javascript if statements?
>
> ```
> var divID = 'tabs' + i;
> if (divID !== null)
> ```

It's useless. `divID` is always a string and never `null`. You probably wanted to test whether `document.getElementById(divID)` did return an element or `null`.

> ```
> }
> if (id == "tab2")
> ```

It's outside the function body, and the `id` variable probably will be undefined.

Better:

```
function ChangeStep(id) {
    for (var i=1; i<3; i++) {
        var div = document.getElementById('tabs' + i);
        if (div !== null)
            div.className = "show"; // or += " show";
                                    // and didn't you want to hide these?
    }
    // show this one
    document.getElementById(id).className = "show";
    // is the `iFrame` variable defined somewhere?
    if (id == "tab2")
        document.getElementById(iFrame).className = "iFrame2";
    else if (id == "tab1") {
        document.getElementById(iFrame).className = "iFrame1";
}
```